# Delphi DirectX Imgae not show on OnCreate

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am having one Delphi DirectX Project wit "DXDraw01", "DXDIB01", "DXDIB02", "Background", "BitBtn01", "BitBtn02, "DXTimer01". My requirement is that the Image stored in "Background" will be displayed when the application will run. According to the DelphiX Tutorial, I have implemented the following codes:

```
unit KoushikHalder01;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Winapi.DirectDraw,
  DXClass, DXDraws, DIB, Math, Menus;

type
  TForm01 = class(TDXForm)
    DXDraw01: TDXDraw;
    DXDIB01: TDXDIB;
    DXDIB02: TDXDIB;
    Background: TDXDIB;
    BitBtn01: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn02: TBitBtn;
    DXTimer01: TDXTimer;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DXTimer01Timer(Sender: TObject; LagCount: Integer);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DXDraw01Finalize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DXDraw01Initialize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form01: TForm01;
  Closing: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm01.DXDraw01Finalize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DXTimer01.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm01.DXDraw01Initialize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DXTimer01.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm01.DXTimer01Timer(Sender: TObject; LagCount: Integer);
begin
  if not DXDraw01.CanDraw then exit;

  DXDraw01.Surface.Fill(0);

  with DXDraw01.Surface.Canvas do
  begin
  DXDraw01.Surface.Assign(Background.DIB);
    Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Font.Color := clWhite;
    Font.Size := 30;
    Textout(130, 30, DateTimeToStr(Now));
    Release; {  Indispensability  }
  end;
  DXDraw01.Flip;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Closing := True;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  DXTimer01.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DXDIB01.Free;
  DXDIB02.Free;
  DXDraw01.Free;
  Background.Free;
end;

end.
```

but it is not happening so. The settings are as follows:
[image: DXDraw Setting] [image: DXTimer Setting]

The "Background" is always in back buffer and not flippint to front buffer and it show on "Desktop" after closing the application unles i refresh my "Desktop". Please, please help me.